# In a Django template, how do I print the value in a dictionary when the key is stored in a variable?

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, templates

I'm using Django and Python 3.7.  In my template, I can see the output of this

```
{{ articlestat.article.website.id }}
```

which is "4".  I have a dictionary, passed to my context, whose keys are numbers.  If I do the following

```
{{ website_stats.4 }}
```

I see a value printed.  However if I do this

```
{{ website_stats[articlestat.article.website.id] }}
```

I get the error

> Could not parse the remainder: '[articlestat.article.website.id]' from 'website_stats[articlestat.article.website.id]'

So my question is, how do I access the value of a dictionary on my template when the key is stored in a variable?  I'm not in a position to hard-code the keys.

Comment: You should do the logic in the view, not the template. Django templates are deliberately restricted not to allow subscriptions and function calls. You can implement a custom template filter, but design-wise that is not a good idea.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot access the dict keys with this syntax in django templates. Usually, we access the key with `{{ my_dict.my_key }}`.

But of course this will not work if you pass a variable like `articlestat.article.website`, all the dots would  messing things up. Even without the dots, the name following the dot cannot be a variable, the template engine uses this name as a string to lookup for a key or a property of this object. (check https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/12486)

If you really cannot match the values from the view, where it is easier to process, this will require a simple [custom template filter](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/howto/custom-template-tags/).

- in a folder `templatetags` in your app, add a file named `custom_filters.py` with this code :

  ```
  from django.template import Library

  register = Library()
  @register.filter
  def lookup(d, key):
      return d.get(key) # simple access here, you can also raise exception in case key is not found
  ```
- in the templates where you need such dict access, add `{% load custom_filters %}` on top,  and use this syntax to call your values :

  ```
  {{ website_stats|lookup:articlestat.article.website.id }}
  ```

Comment: I don't see any folder "templatetags" in my app.  Is this something that should be auto-created or do I need to create it myself, and if so, where?

Comment: No it's not here by default, you create it if you need to use custom filters, in your app folder, next to `migrations`, `templates` ..